# Not able to access global variables across activity

Tags: java, android-studio, global-variables

In this code, I want the strings sh1, shg2 and shg3 to be displayed according to the users input in text edit. I have created a saver class to set and retrieve the variables. But although they are global variables, shg1 ,sh2 and sh3 do not store the values and don't display anything. Thanks for your help

Saver class:

```
public class Saver extends Application {

public String shg1,shg2,shg3;

public String getShg1() {
    return shg1;
}

public void setShg1(String s1) {
    shg1= s1;
}
public String getShg2() {
    return shg2;
}

public void setShg2(String s1) {
    shg2= s1;
}
public String getShg3() {
    return shg3;
}

public void setShg3(String s1) {
    shg3= s1;
}
}
```

SHGDetails class:

```
public class SHGDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shgdetails);

    final EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shg1);
    final EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shg2);
    final EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shg3);
    final Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    final LinearLayout l = findViewById(R.id.linearl);
    final TextView t1 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView t2 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final TextView t3 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    e1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    e2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    e3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
    Saver s = new Saver();

    if (isFirstRun) {
        //show start activity
            b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        e3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         String text = e1.getText().toString();
         String text2 = e2.getText().toString();
         String text3 = e3.getText().toString();
        ((Saver) this.getApplication()).setShg1(text);
        ((Saver) this.getApplication()).setShg2(text2);
        ((Saver) this.getApplication()).setShg3(text3);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                l.removeView(e1);
                l.removeView(e2);
                l.removeView(e3);
                l.removeView(b1);

                getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();


            }
        });
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s.getShg1(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        t1.setText(((Saver) this.getApplication()).getShg1());
        t2.setText(((Saver) this.getApplication()).getShg2());
        t3.setText(((Saver) this.getApplication()).getShg3());
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch data and set when user press the button so there's no values before button click so do this

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

         // 
               String text = e1.getText().toString();
               String text2 = e2.getText().toString();
               String text3 = e3.getText().toString();
              ((Saver) SHGDetails.this.getApplication()).setShg1(text);
              ((Saver) SHGDetails.this.getApplication()).setShg2(text2);
              ((Saver) SHGDetails.this.getApplication()).setShg3(text3);

                l.removeView(e1);
                l.removeView(e2);
                l.removeView(e3);
                l.removeView(b1);

                getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                        .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();


            }
        });
```

and seems like you already have registered your application in manifest.

Comment: Thanks but the program gives me this error:Error:(56, 34) error: cannot find symbol method getApplication()

Comment: use `SHGDetails.this.getApplication()` because onclick is using an anonymous click `new view.onclic..` so `this` will point to that class instead of activity

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding